# Drawing a circle without using a function for it

Tags: graphics, geometry

So I was wondering how does a `circle()` function work, and how can I draw to circle without using it (wanted to do something related to it). Does anyone know this stuff?

Comment: Start with the [equation of a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations).

Comment: Didn't learn stuff related to circles in school yet,thanks for the info!

Comment: Hmm, well that makes things more difficult. It's often the case that good software engineers have a good understanding of mathematics. And this is an example of why. Especially in computer graphics, software algorithms are often based on advanced mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

A classic way of rasterizing a circle is using the [Midpoint Circle Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm).

It works by tracking the pixels which are as close to the x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> = r<sup>2</sup> isoline as possible. This can even be done with purely integer calculations, which is particularly suitable for low-computation power devices.

Answer (score 0):

A circle is the set of points located at a constant distance from another point, called the center.

If you can draw `lines` defined by two `points`, you can draw the representation of a `circle` on a canvas, knowing its `center`, and its `radius`.

The approach is to determine a set of consecutive points located on the circumference, then join them with lines.

for instance, in python (which reads like pseudocode):

```
import math

def make_circle(center, radius, num_points=40):
    """returns a sequence of points on the circumference
    """ 
    points = [center]
    d_theta = 2 * math.pi / num_points
    cx, cy = center
    for idx in range(num_points + 1):
        theta = idx * d_theta
        points.append((cx + math.cos(theta) * radius, cy + math.sin(theta) * radius))
    return points
```

And if you want to try it, here it is: [circles codeskulptor](https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user303_iRcDu3t6tD_0.py).
You will see that for display purposes, 40 points on the circumference is enough to give an acceptable rendition.